# Steps for Upgrading Ruby Installer for Windows from 1.8.6 to 1.8.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

I need to upgrade Ruby from 1.8.6 to 1.8.7 on Windows and I use the one click installer. I don't use ScITE (I do use RubyMine but I don't think that makes any difference).

If anyone has done this successfully I would appreciate knowing what steps you took. For example did you uninstall 1.8.6 first? I assume that afterwards I will need to manually install gems but not plugins? And are there any pitfalls to watch out for?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you installed Ruby using One-Click Installer, then I would suggest you leave that installation alone and install newer RubyInstaller in a new directory.

RubyInstaller and One-Click differ a lot in technical aspects, which could affect your upgrade path (override or install on top of it)

Also, old One-Click Installer had the bad habit of removing your gems and customizations, something that could make you pull your hair.

My recommendation would be:

1. Get a list of all your installed gems (`gem list`) in case you want to install them again
2. Install RubyInstaller in a different directory (by default will be `C:\Ruby187`)
3. Install your missing gems

If you use Rails and Bundler, then gem installation beyond `gem install bundler` will not be necessary.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

my opinion:

uninstall ruby 1.8.6 and install 1.8.7.

you won't need to worry about the gems, at least if you're using rails3, you can run a bundle install for a project and everything is done automatically (you'll probably run into problems if using mysql2, but for development, sqlite3 or the old mysql will be fine)